# Ember RSVP Promise resolve always returns undefined value

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-simple-auth

I'm using Ember-simple-auth and trying to return data from my custom authenticator back into the controller that did the authenticating.

in my authenticator/custom.js:

```
  authenticate(identification, password) {
      return  new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          var loginURL = 'https://domain.com/login';    
          var authObj = Ember.Object.create({"identity":identification,"password":password});
          var hash = authObj.getProperties('identity', 'password');
          var stringHash = JSON.stringify(hash);

              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("post", loginURL);
              xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
              xhr.responseType = 'json';
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Format', 'JSON');
              xhr.send(stringHash);

              function handler() {
                if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                  if (this.status === 200) {
                    console.log('response is: ',this.response); /// <-- returns good response data
                    resolve(this.response);
                  } else {
                      reject( 'failed with status: [' + this.status + ']');

                  }
                }
            }
```

and in my login controller:

```
 authenticate() {
  let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');

  var session = this.get('session');
  session.authenticate('authenticator:custom', identification, password).then((reason) => {
            console.log('failed login',reason);
        });   
    }
},
```

But I'd really like to be able to handle the `resolve` function and get it's `value` payload from the `authenticate` promise.

If I change the `.catch` to a `.then` the response function is successfully called but always has an undefined value as its payload:

```
  session.authenticate('authenticator:custom', identification, password).then(
      (response) => {
          console.log('response: ',response); //// <---- always 'undefined'
            this.setUserWithData(response);
        },
      (reason) => {
            this.set('Login failed: ',reason);
        }       

    );    
    }
```

Even if I restructure the promise, rearrange how the function is called, the first function from an RSVP is successfully called, but has an undefined payload.  The second function from an RSVP always has a correct payload.

I tried reversing the resolve/reject:

```
Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject){
```

to

```
Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (reject, resolve){
```

and the function successfully carries the response, but the simple-auth now believes it has failed its authorization.

I'd like to be able to pass the response payload into my controller.  Or, if that can't be done, how can I inject data from the response into my session and ember-data store?  It didn't seem like good practice to call and insert data into the store from within the authenticate function of the authenticator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session's `authenticate` method doesn't resolve with a value. Check the API docs: http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html#method_authenticate

Comment: I see. That explains it.  It does seem to break the expected syntax though. Thanks for your work on Simple-auth.  Is there an example of how to design a custom authenticator?  All the links you've previously posted to examples no longer work.  It's tricky to figure out the best practices for a simple but custom authenticator.

Answer (score 2):

In order to deal with the response from the authentication route, I used the function `sessionAuthenticated` to deal with the returned data.

So, the `authenticate` function in `authenticators/custom.js`

```
  authenticate(identification, password) {

      return  new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 

          var loginURL = 'https://domain.com/login';    
          var authObj = Ember.Object.create({"identity":identification,"password":password});
          var hash = authObj.getProperties('identity', 'password');
          var stringHash = JSON.stringify(hash);

              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("post", loginURL);
              xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
              xhr.responseType = 'json';
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Format', 'JSON');
              xhr.send(stringHash);

              function handler() {
                if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                  if (this.status === 200) {
                    console.log('200 response: \r',this.response);
                    resolve(this.response);
                  } else {
                    console.log('failure response',this.response);
                      reject(this.response);
                  }
                }
            }
        });

  },
```

With the `sessionAuthenticated()` event taking place in `routes/application.js`:

```
sessionAuthenticated: function(){
    var session = this.get('session');
    var data = session.get('data');
    var response = data.authenticated;
    console.log('sessionAuthenticated()',response);
},
sessionInvalidated: function(){
    console.log('sessionInvalidated()',response);
},
```

From the `sessionAuthenticated` function, the `response` variable contains all the information passed to it from `authenticate(response)` inside the authenticator.